# Using custom Cortana skills with the Cortana Invoke

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-invoke

I've written a bot with the Bot framework and gotten it working with Cortana on Windows and Android.  I just unpacked a new Cortana Invoke to test it with today, but I can't figure out how to register it there.

For my Amazon Echo, I was able to register my custom skill in the app and start using it with the Echo right away.

Am I missing something, or does the standalone Cortana Invoke not support custom skills yet?

Comment: Are you logged into Cortana with the same account you used to register the skill on dev.botframework.com?  This sounds like you just are not logged into the right account.

Comment: Different account, but one that was added to the group.  I'm logged in with the same account on the android device, where it works just fine.  Today, even the built-in stuff is behaving odd on the Invoke... I may just have a defective one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was user error.

The syntax is "Hey Cortana, ask  to ".  I was missing the "Hey" part...

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary that you need to use the word 'Ask', there are a wide range possibilities like:

1. Ask
2. Tell
3. Use
4. Open
5. Start
6. Search
7. Get
8. Have
9. Check
10. See if

For more details refer to [cortana invocation guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/cortana-invocation-guidelines)